Property alias: "Invalid alias target location" unless property is bound
Why doesn't this work:
    property alias monitorLabelText: monitorForm.monitorLabel.text

    header: MonitorForm {
        id: monitorForm
    }

It fails with Invalid alias target location: text.
But this works:
    property alias monitorLabelText: monitorForm.monitorLabel.text

    header: MonitorForm {
        id: monitorForm
        monitorLabel.text: '' // added
    }

And so does this (once I create the monitorLabelText alias in MonitorForm.qml):
    property alias monitorLabelText: monitorForm.monitorLabelText // <-

    header: MonitorForm {
        id: monitorForm
    }

MWE:
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication()
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load('test.qml')
app.exec()

// test.qml
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    property alias monitorLabelText: monitorForm.monitorLabel.text
    MonitorForm {
        id: monitorForm
        monitorLabel.text: ''
    }
}

// MonitorForm.qml
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
GridLayout {
    property alias monitorLabel: monitorLabel
    Label { id: monitorLabel }
}

Tested with PySide6-6.7.2 and QtDeclarative-6.7.2.

I think it's a bug, but I can only confirm this in Qt 6.8; I don't have access to older versions.

smr In case it is a bug, I've reported it (QTBUG-130605)
